# `[(ngModel)]` doesn't get value from contoller, how to fix?

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I have a todo list project where every entry is an input (inline modification).

```
<div *ngFor="let t of todos;" class="list-item">
  <span class="list-item__checkbox">&nbsp;</span>
  <textarea class="todo-item__textarea"
    (input)="onTodoKeyEvent($event, t)"
    (keydown)="onTodoKeyEvent($event, t)"
    ([ngModel])="t.text"
    ></textarea>
  {{t.text}}
</div>
```

The `onTodoKeyEvent` method invokes update function, to update todo data in array.

```
onTodoKeyEvent(event, todo) {
  this.updateTodo({
    id: todo.id,
    text: event.target.value + 'additional text'
  });
}
```

I get todos into controller from service using getter:

```
get todos(): Todo[] {
  return this.todoDataService.get();
}
```

Update function:

```
update(data: Todo) {
  let todo = this.todos[data.id];
  Object.assign(todo, data);
}
```

The problem is that I can see new data in `todos` array, and in view at `{{t.text}}`, but the value inside textarea, model value, is the same as was typed, so it feels like one-way binding.
[image]

Why is that, how can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `[(ngModel)]="t.text"`, not `([ngModel])="t.text"`.

They call it [Bananas in a box](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3008-two-way-data-binding-is-just-a-box-of-bananas-in-angular-2-beta-1.htm):

this is the box: `[ ]`
and these are the bananas: `( )`

Comment: Funny ;) Thanks, I was lost.

Comment: @Georgy this kind of things happen pretty often to me... Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: You even used the correct syntax in the question title, haha.